# Feature-Policy fullscreen not working as expected

Tags: nginx, http-headers, video

I have NGINX running as a reverse proxy and set the Feature-Policy header with fullscreen to "self". The site itself contains the HTML5 video player, but unless I set fullscreen to "*" the fullscreen button on the video player is disabled. What could cause it to be disabled when set to "self" (or origin for that matter)?

Here's the Feature-Policy (so far, because I noticed there are still a few more I could add):

```
    add_header Feature-Policy "
    accelerometer none;
    ambient-light-sensor none;
    autoplay self;
    camera none;
    document-write none;
    encrypted-media self;
    fullscreen self;
    geolocation none;
    gyroscope none;
    layout-animations self;
    lazyload self;
    legacy-image-formats self;
    magnetometer none;
    microphone none;
    midi none;
    notifications none;
    oversized-images self;
    payment none;
    picture-in-picture self;
    push none; 
    speaker self;
    sync-script none;
    sync-xhr none;
    unoptimized-images self;
    unsized-media self;
    usb none;
    vertical-scroll self;
    vibrate none; 
    vr none;";
```

And here's an example of a video player:

```
<video playsinline controls autoplay preload="auto">
    <source src="/stream/364a42a508d89886d277f779dafb51b7" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

There's no added JavaScript or anything.

**UPDATE:**

The video URL is a stream and not the actual video file, but it is still served locally. Other features that don't work: picture in picture and click to pause/play (only with the actual button).

Comment: Is that the actual stream URL or does it redirect to somewhere else?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes it's the actual URL, no redirect (but it is a stream and not the actual file itself). Just noticed autoplay and picture-in-picture don't work either.

Comment: Fullscreen and picture-in-picture are working for me in Firefox, but I have autoplay blocked so I can't really test that. There are some [oddities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKoCi.png), like image sprites appearing in odd places...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Apparently autoplay does work in Chrome and Edge (I tested it on Chromium at the time), so that's really weird. :) Are there any issues with settings it to all?